# VS- CODE errors on manjaro, auto quit, can't open folder

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, archlinux, manjaro

I have been using vs code for a month now on my manjaro Linux machine and I've had a number of issues. For example **opening a folder from the welcome page** doesn't work, **sign in using a GitHub account** doesn't work, it hangs quite a lot and after facing any of these issues vs code quits
I have tried to re-install vs-code but it solves nothing

I am using a laptop with an i7 8th gen CPU, 16GB ram and a G-force MX150 which should be plenty for everything but I'm booting into manjaro using a traditional old hard drive

Is there a fix for this ?

Comment: Perhaps you could share more information. Can you post or link a screen capture of these issues?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Tlt7E0PhHd4 But I must mention I downloaded the app using snap on manjaro

Comment: I looked at VS Code's github and there are number of similar issues. Links: [1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61091), [2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56342), [3](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/56594). It looks like they all happen on Linux. Do you have the latest stable build of VS Code? Also you can look at [crash reporting wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Native-Crash-Issues#linux) that will guide through the process of creating an issue with more information.

Comment: Yes, I do have the latest build. I have tried some of the solutions which suggested reinstalling glibc but it made no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I just figured out to solve this problem myself
follow the steps below if you're facing similar issues on an arch-based distro. The problem is with the AUR pls
download the official release from GitHub if you're not sure how to do that follow the steps below.

1. uninstall VS-code
2. cd into the desired directory
3. Follow the steps in order

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/visual-studio-code-bin.git
```

```
cd visual-studio-code-bin
```

```
makepkg -si
```

This solved my issue so I hope it does for you as well