# EOF error in VS-code (not Working in terminal also)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I use vs-code on Manjaro ann I've had numerous issues with it explained in this question following [VS- CODE errors on manjaro, auto quit, can't open folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533866/vs-code-errors-on-manjaro-auto-quit-cant-open-folder)

I have the following code

```
import cv2
from random import randrange
#load data
trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

#Choose image
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    successful_frame_read, frame = webcam.read()

    #convert to greyscale
    greyscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    #detect faces
    face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(greyscaled_img)

    #Draw a rectangle around the Face
    for (x, y, w, h) in face_coordinates:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0, 10)
    
    #Display the image with the faces spotted
    cv2.imshow('Face detector', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    #stop if Q is pressed
    if key==81 or key==113:
    break

webcam.release()
print("code completed")
```

In the beginning, I had a syntax  error at

```
  File "Face_detector.py", line 24
    cv2.imshow('Face detector', frame)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I commented out the line but got the same error in the next line

```
  File "Face_detector.py", line 25
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I went ahead and commented out every sing line till the end
and now I got an EOF error

```
 File "Face_detector.py", line 33

                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I tried running the script from the terminal but still has the exact same error

[Here is an image of running the uncommented code from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoZ2b.png)

[Here is an image of running the final commented out code from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z03o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a parentheses at this line:

```py
#Draw a rectangle around the Face
for (x, y, w, h) in face_coordinates:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0, 10) # <-- Missing parentheses here
```

Comment: Okay, So I fixed it But now I have this error. I believe there's something wrong with the open cv implementation. I'd appreciate it if you'd like to help me

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/smokedpirate/Documents/1. Python_learning/3_recognition/Realtime_face_detector/Face_detector.py", line 17, in <module> face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(greyscaled_img) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'

Comment: I suggest looking at some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508922/error-215-empty-in-function-detectmultiscale).